# mix-blend-mode on image with no background

Tags: css, image, background, mix-blend-mode

I'm facing a problem with using mix-blend-mode css property on an image without background. The use of this property works only if I set a background color to my image but i don't want to have a square frame around my image.

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Thanks

```
<div class="container">
  
  <!-- Image with img tag -->
  <img class="logo" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/220/220124.png?w=360" alt="">
  
  <!-- Image with background-image -->
  <div class="logo-background"></div>
  
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
  
</div>
```

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 20;
}

.logo-background {
  background: url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/220/220124.png?w=360");
  background-color: white;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, calc(-100% - 25px));
  z-index: 20;
}

.block {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  border: solid 2px black;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.header {
  background: crimson;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
}

.footer {
  background: lightcoral;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/alain-nobilito/pen/oNaoJJp

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The difference between any color and black is that color. What color are you wanting?